# edit: trouble checking if file is empty or not, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, fileinputstream

Edit: changed my question to be more accurate of the situation

I'm trying to open up a text file (create it if it doesnt exist,open it if it doesnt). It is the same input file as output.

```
ofstream oFile("goalsFile.txt");
fstream iFile("goalsFile.txt");
string goalsText;   
string tempBuffer;
//int fileLength = 0;
bool empty = false;

if (oFile.is_open())
{
    if (iFile.is_open())
    {
        iFile >> tempBuffer;
        iFile.seekg(0, iFile.end);
        size_t fileLength = iFile.tellg();
        iFile.seekg(0, iFile.beg);
        if (fileLength == 0) 
        {
            cout << "Set a new goal\n" << "Goal Name:"; //if I end debugging her the file ends up being empty
            getline(cin, goalSet);
            oFile << goalSet;
            oFile << ";";
            cout << endl;

            cout << "Goal Cost:";
            getline(cin, tempBuffer);
            goalCost = stoi(tempBuffer);
            oFile << goalCost;
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Couple of issues. For one, if the file exist and has text within it, it still goes into the if loop that would normally ask me to set a new goal. I can't seem to figure out what's happening here.

Comment: sigh..
why the downvotes?

Comment: Seek to the end, and get the position. If it's zero then the file is empty.

Comment: Yes, but why doesnt what I have work and why is what's happening, happening?.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I attempted to use what I am understanding of seek to the end, and it still does not work, any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simply that you are using buffered IO streams. Despite the fact that they reference the same file underneath, they have completely separate buffers.

```
// open the file for writing and erase existing contents.
std::ostream out(filename);
// open the now empty file for reading.
std::istream in(filename);
// write to out's buffer
out << "hello";
```

At this point, "hello" may not have been written to disk, the only guarantee is that it's in the output buffer of `out`. To force it to be written to disk you could use

```
out << std::endl;  // new line + flush
out << std::flush; // just a flush
```

that means that we've committed our output to disk, but the input buffer is still untouched at this point, and so the file still appears to be empty.

In order for your input file to see what you've written to the output file, you'd need to use `sync`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

static const char* filename = "testfile.txt";

int main()
{
    std::string hello;

    {
        std::ofstream out(filename);
        std::ifstream in(filename);
        out << "hello\n";
        in >> hello;
        std::cout << "unsync'd read got '" << hello << "'\n";
    }

    {
        std::ofstream out(filename);
        std::ifstream in(filename);
        out << "hello\n";

        out << std::flush;
        in.sync();

        in >> hello;
        std::cout << "sync'd read got '" << hello << "'\n";
    }
}
```

The next problem you'll run into trying to do this with buffered streams is the need to `clear()` the eof bit on the input stream every time more data is written to the file...

Comment: in regards to this and my code then without trying to read the contents and just check if it's empty it will always be empty? Considering I want to check if it already has the contents or not THEN decide what to do with it (in this case get the goal's from the user). 

By using sync, then doing the check, your suggesting this could be my solution? 
I'm not sure how to use "sync" in line with my code situation.

Comment: The code you posted starts by opening the file for writing in non-append mode, which does infact make the file empty. If you want to know if the file is empty, test it before you open it for writing. 1/ Test if you can open it, i.e if the file exists; 2/ Test if you are at eof without reading, if so, then the file is empty.

Comment: OMG APPEND MODE. That was the whole problem over everything, thank you idk how I overlooked that. Thank you for the sync idea though, that's a really neat thing I've never looked into

Answer (score 1):

Try [Boost::FileSystem::is_empty](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#is_empty) which test if your file is empty. I read somewhere that using fstream's is not a good way to test empty files.

Comment: I'm not to sure what that is to be exactly :/

Comment: @Robolisk is a portable library with good templates and functions to perform platform independ task, such file exists, empty files, file sizes, etc., there are many examples on the net about how to use them, like this [one](http://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.filesystem-files-and-directories), which show some examples of the library with files.